# Opção menu volta para login

Tags: html, menu, treeview, angular-6, submenu

Estou tentando usar o treeview do AdminLTE no menu do sistema, mas toda vez que clico no item do menu ele volta para o login.

Por exemplo:

Quando eu clico em Dashboard, Grafico ou Gerenciamento, ele volta pra o login

Trecho do treeview em HTML:

```
<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
    <span>Gerenciamento</span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
       <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li class="treeview">
      <a>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><span>Digiboard</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
           <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><a routerLinkActive="ative" [routerLink]="['/gerenciar-dispositivo']"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i>Gerenciamento de dispositivos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Esse é o menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Rotas:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'sistema',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'estacao', loadChildren: './estacao/estacao.module#EstacaoModule' },
      {path: 'gerenciar-dispositivo', loadChildren: './gerenciar-dispositivos/gerenciar-dispositivos.module#GerenciarDispositivosModule'}
    ]
  },
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: ':to', component: LoginComponent}
 ]
```

Toda vez que eu clico no menu ele volta para o login, por que?

Comment: Já tentou colocar um preventDefault() no link a?

Comment: bom, neste caso parou de funcionar, tentei assim: `<a (click)="$event.preventDefault()">`

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de JS, mas acho que preventDefault() é dferente de stopPropagation()... ou é tudo a mesma coisa? Eu sugeri isso pq já vi alguns menus em JS que quando vc clica em um a com href="#"  a tela rolava pro topo e resolveu usando preventDefault()

Comment: É que estou usando angular e não js